# $L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{\arcsin(x(e^x-1))}$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

Find the limit $$L=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{\arcsin(x(e^x-1))}$$

Okay, so my try:

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{\arcsin(x(e^x-1))}\cdot\dfrac{x(e^x-1)}{x(e^x-1)}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{x(e^x-1)}\cdot\dfrac{x}{x}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{x^2}$$

I decided to use Taylor series here centered at $0$, so $$(2x+1)^\frac12=1+x-x^2+O(x^3)\\(1+4x)^\frac14=1+x-3x^2+O(x^3)$$

May someone clarify for me what does $O(x^3)$ exactly mean and if my calculations were right? Then the limit becomes $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1+x-x^2+O(x^3)-1-x+3x^2-O(x^3)}{x^2}=2,$$ but the answer is $1$.

Comment: Check the coefficient of $x^2$ in both Taylor series.  I get half of those values.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, well, isn't it ${\frac12\choose 2} (2x)^2=-x^2$ for the first Taylor?

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ at $0$ is $1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+O(x^3)$.  Then, when you substitute $2x$ for $x$, you get $1+x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$.  I'm not sure what you mean by $\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{2}$, but perhaps you're missing the $2!$?

Comment: Instead of using the Taylor series, you could multiply by the conjugate of the numerator twice.

Comment: You can take $\sqrt[4]{1+4x}$ common from both terms in numerator and since it tends to $1$ you can ignore this factor. The remaining fraction is easily handled by putting $t=\sqrt{1+2x}/\sqrt[4]{1+4x}$ and noting that $(t^4-1)/x^2\to 4$.

Comment: Further $\binom{1/2} {2}(2x)^2=-x^2/2$ and thus your computation of binomial coefficients has an error.

Answer (score 1):

We have that, following your fine idea

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{\arcsin(x(e^x-1))}=\frac{x}{e^x-1}\frac{x(e^x-1)}{\arcsin(x(e^x-1))}\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{x^2} \to 1$$

indeed by standard limits the first two factors tend to $1$ and since

- $(2x+1)^\frac12=1+x-\color{red}{\frac{x^2}2}+O(x^3)$
- $(1+4x)^\frac14=1+x-\color{red}{\frac32x^2}+O(x^3)$

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{x^2}=\frac{x^2+O(x^3)}{x^2}=1+O(x) \to 1$$

As an alternative for the last factor using that $A^4-B^4=(A-B)(A+B)(A^2+B^2)$ we have

$$\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}-\sqrt[4]{4x+1}}{x^2}=\frac{(2x+1)^2-(4x+1)}{x^2(\sqrt{2x+1}+\sqrt[4]{4x+1})(2x+1+\sqrt{4x+1})}\to 1$$

Comment: I think there is a mistake: $$-\frac{x^2}2+\frac32 x^2=x^2\ne 2x^2$$So the limit in the first case is $1$, not $2$

Comment: yes of course! I fix that, thanks